# rsync insidious failure

Tags: rsync

I'm trying to use rsync to make a remote dir identical to my local version,
so I do something like (with the "my" stuff below suitably replaced)

```
rsync -avhe 'ssh -p 7822' --progress --delete  \
    /mylocaldir myusername@myremotehost:~/myremotedir`
```

The output of the command indicates warnings but no error message :

```
perl: warning: Setting locale failed.
perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:
    LANGUAGE = (unset),
    LC_ALL = (unset),
    LC_NUMERIC = "c",
    LANG = "fr_FR.UTF-8"
    are supported and installed on your system.
perl: warning: Falling back to the standard locale ("C").
building file list ... 
70 files to consider
Online/index.html
         582 100%    0.00kB/s    0:00:00 (xfer#1, to-check=67/70)

sent 2.28K bytes  received 48 bytes  665.71 bytes/sec
total size is 919.11K  speedup is 394.47
```

But when I check on the remote dir, nothing has been updated. I tried it several times.
What is happening here ? 
Any help appreciated.

Update, in answer to the first comment below : here is the content of my /etc/profile file :

```
# System-wide .profile for sh(1)

if [ -x /usr/libexec/path_helper ]; then
    eval `/usr/libexec/path_helper -s`
fi

if [ "${BASH-no}" != "no" ]; then
    [ -r /etc/bashrc ] && . /etc/bashrc
fi
```

Comment: You have commands in your `/etc/profile` (or whatever) that produce output when run in non-interactive shells.  This breaks the `rsync` protocol.  Basically you need to identify those commands, and run them only when `$-` contains `i`.

Comment: @SatōKatsura When i do `echo $-`, I get `himBH`, so my `$-` does contain `i`.

Comment: Your `$-` does contain `i` in interactive shells.  This doesn't happen when the (remote) shell is run from `rsync`.

Comment: @SatōKatsura  So, in your above comment you meant the remote /etc/profile , not the local one ?

Comment: I'm referring to something in the startup sequence of your remote shell.  That might be `/etc/profile` or some other config file.

Comment: @SatōKatsura the unexpected locale error message is not breaking `rsync` - it's working just fine. Otherwise you'd not see any of the transfer progress messages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`rsync` is running, so the locale error message is not critical. Instead, I suspect that your two directory definitions are not quite what you want, and you may be looking in the wrong place for the files.

You have a source `/mylocaldir` and a destination `~/myremotedir`. This will create `~/myremotedir/mylocaldir` on the target, and that's where the files will be placed.

If you want the contents of `/mylocaldir` to be copied to `~/myremotedir` you need to provide a trailing `/` on the source directory, like this:

```
rsync -avh -e 'ssh -p 7822' --progress --delete \
    /mylocaldir/ myusername@myremotehost:myremotedir
```

<sub>NB I've split the command over two lines for readability. As written it's valid shell syntax, but remove the `\` character on the end of the first line and join them together if you prefer.</sub>

---

The perl error message about locales will be coming from some program that's executed as part of your login process. It might be `path_helper`, which seems to be a MacOS application so I can't advise you on the importance or otherwise of commenting it out, or it could be something in `/etc/bashrc`.

Rather than trying to identify the offending application, another option, of course, is to install the French locale files on your target system, so that the error is no longer triggered.

Comment: Many thanks! Each and every one of your guesses is absolutely right (but you already knew that, didn't you ? :-) ), and now I added the missing slash it's working fine. Could you please elaborate just a little on how to install locale files on my Mac ?

Comment: Ah ... Judging from several answers here on MSE, such as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7165108/in-os-x-lion-lang-is-not-set-to-utf-8-how-to-fix-it and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9991603/add-a-locale-in-mac-osx, this is not a simple problem. I'll ask it as a separate question